# Why does this function return only true, since there is no else statement to make it return false under a non true condition?

Tags: javascript, function

It seems to me that this bit of code is asking the function to return false regardless of what is internally going on. I only know to use `else` statements to return false values, but maybe there is something behind the scenes that I am not seeing that someone else could explain?

> Challenge: Create a function that takes two arguments, an array of numbers (arr) and a number value (n). All you need to do is check whether the provided array contains the number value (n) or not. Return true if the array contains the value, false if not.

```js
function isItThere(arr, n) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === n) {
            return 'true';
        }
    } return 'false';
}

console.log(isItThere([1,3,5,6,7,8,9], 3));
```

Comment: The function has two points of exit. As soon as one of them is reached the function exits with the supplied return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return `'false'` statement is executed only after the array is exhausted and the element is not found.

```js
function isItThere(arr, n) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === n) {
            return 'true';
        }
    } 
    return 'false';//after the array search is done and not found
}

console.log(isItThere([1,3,5,6,7,8,9], 3));
console.log(isItThere([1,3,5,6,7,8,9], 100));
```